# Compile OpenBR to ArmV7 - Android toolchain issue

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk, cmake

I've successfully gone through the [install/build instructions for OpenBR on linux](http://openbiometrics.org/doxygen/latest/linux_gcc.html)

My goal is to build and run OpenBR on android.

After a ton of tinkering, I finally successfully built OpenBR for armv7.  My problem is that when I do "System.loadLibrary("openbr")" I get the error:

```
11-25 23:40:31.221: E/dalvikvm(29742): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.test.app-28/libopenbr.so") failed: dlopen failed: could not load library "/home/ubuntu/qt5.1.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Concurrent.so.5.1.1" needed by "libopenbr.so"; caused by library "/home/ubuntu/qt5.1.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Concurrent.so.5.1.1" not found
```

I believe I have correctly included armv7 libQt5Concurrent library (loading as local module in android.mk), but I think the problem is that libopenbr is looking in the wrong directory when it goes to load (as seen in the error message).  It's trying to look in a path on the compile machine.

Running readelf on libopenbr.so yields this:

```
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [/home/ubuntu/qt5.1.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Concurrent.so.5.1.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [/home/ubuntu/qt5.1.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.1.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [/home/ubuntu/qt5.1.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5.1.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [/home/ubuntu/qt5.1.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Network.so.5.1.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [/home/ubuntu/qt5.1.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Sql.so.5.1.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [/home/ubuntu/qt5.1.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.1.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [/home/ubuntu/qt5.1.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Xml.so.5.1.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libz.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libdl.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [liblog.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so]
```

How do I get it so the Qt libraries are NOT searched using this path from compile time?

I've tried a variety of cmake directives including various permutations of these variables in the openbr CMakeLists.txt:

```
SET(CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH TRUE)

# use, i.e. don't skip the full RPATH for the build tree
SET(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  TRUE)

# when building, don't use the install RPATH already
# (but later on when installing)
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)

# the RPATH to be used when installing
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "")

# don't add the automatically determined parts of the RPATH
# which point to directories outside the build tree to the install RPATH
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH FALSE)
```

Any help getting this path out of the shared library paths for my built library would be great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I actually finally figured out how to fix this by updating the cmake files each qt lib to not include the version string at the end of the filename!

Answer (score 0):

When loading a dynamic library with System.loadLibrary(), you need to open all dependencies first, because System.loadLibrary()  won't load them for you.

So probably you have to do :
System.loadLibrary("libQt5Concurrent")
System.loadLibrary("openbr")

If libQt5Concurrent has other dependecies, you'll have to load them the same way before.

Comment: Gerald, I'm able to load qt5concurrent successfully before openbr.  however, openbr seems to be looking at the hardcoded path from my compile machine for qt5concurrent and fails out.

Comment: It's in my post:

11-25 23:40:31.221: E/dalvikvm(29742): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.test.app-28/libopenbr.so") failed: dlopen failed: could not load library "/home/ubuntu/qt5.1.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Concurrent.so.5.1.1" needed by "libopenbr.so"; caused by library "/home/ubuntu/qt5.1.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Concurrent.so.5.1.1" not found

I believe the problem is that it's hard coded to look at /home/ubuntu/qt5.1.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Concurrent.so.5.1.1 to load the library but that path obviously doesnt exist on the system.

Comment: It sounds like a link issue. Do you compile the QT libs yourself?  Here, I'm using cmake, and I see that the command line has something like this in the link command line : -shared -Wl,-soname,libMyLib.so, if I remember correctly, it's to avoid hard coded path. Check if you can link the QT libs using this.